# Visual Studio PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-2005

I've used VS.PHP (http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) for years with great success, but I've run out of licensing on all my machines and I want to have a unified development environment for my PHP programming.

Granted it's only $99 and I enjoy paying for code that helps me out, but I have too many home machines and would rather spend that $99 on boats or booze.

I would love to stay in Visual Studio(2005) and was wondering if there is a good open source alternative plugin for PHP development in Visual Studio that anyone knows about.

Thanks.

Comment: $99 wouldn't even fill the boat with gas, looks like you'll be drinking instead!

Answer (score 9):

There is standalone [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5) (freeware and trial) which I would recommend; simple, fast, smart IntelliSense with an option to use it completely free

Answer (score 6):

there's [phalanger](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/BE3906D3-2C6E-4C45-B1F4-AB8DA01B339C)

Comment: keep in mind, this looks like it compiles php code into a dll. However, this can always be used to write the code and test it, then just deploy the php files.

Comment: Note Phalanger is an alternative to PHP for .NET - as a part of the package it contains its integration into Visual Studio. So it actually adds support for Phalanger (which is almost the same as PHP). As a side-effect you will migrate your PHP app to .NET :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which may not be quite as robust as VS and third party add-ons, but it does support PHP out of the box!

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is free and available on Linux, Mac OSX, and Windows"

You can also add PHP debugging with the [vscode-php-debug](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) extension.