# How to add php files to visual studio project?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010

I need to add php files to visual studio project.There is no option to add it using "Add item".if i externally add it to project,the code is not readable by compiler.
is there any solution?

Comment: Use `Add Item` and check that at the bottom of the dialog your Filetype is set to 'All Files' or just type in '*.*' (without quotes) in the Filename box and hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here : [How can I add PHP support to Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678282/how-can-i-add-php-support-to-visual-studio-2010?rq=1)

or here : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5

or here : [Visual Studio PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009476/visual-studio-php)